# gcc can't compile R packages under Linux Mint: can't find stdlib.h

Tags: r, compiler-errors, installation, package, linux-mint

I'm trying to install the R package gtools from the Linux Mint command line. After choosing the closest CRAN mirror, I'm getting the error message that no such file or directory was found and that installation of the package had a non-zero exit status. More specifically:

```
> install.packages('gtools')
Installing package into ‘/home/lizi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-
project.org/src/contrib/gtools_3.5.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 64855 bytes (63 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 63 KB

* installing *source* package ‘gtools’ ...
** package ‘gtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c roman2int.c -o roman2int.o
In file included from roman2int.c:1:0:
/usr/share/R/include/R.h:55:80: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or 
directory
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:159: recipe for target 'roman2int.o' failed
make: *** [roman2int.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘gtools’
* removing ‘/home/lizi/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/gtools’

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/Rtmp0z5PS6/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("gtools") :
  installation of package ‘gtools’ had non-zero exit status
```

The package has no dependencies, and I was under the impression that install.packages was straightforward. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A similar question on your same distro: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184167/error-in-installing-package-fatal-error-stdlib-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: But the important line in question (for yours) is `fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory`. Looks like you're missing the `stdlib` header R needs for compilation

Comment: Try a different repo. I got a similar error right now with that repo , but the Berkeley repo delivers good code.

Comment: Try a different repo, and/or a different version of gtools, and please confirm if this still happens.

Comment: **Duplicate**. The underlying gcc error is not finding stdlib.h . See all the **duplicates for ["no stdlib.h"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgcc%5D+no+stdlib.h)**. Check your gcc install, command-line, related environment variables etc.